# New mobile chat doesn't follow the keyboard height

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web, mobile-safari, ios

The Japanese keyboard on iOS dynamically changes it's height to show suggestions and hides the input box of new mobile chat.

> [image: jp kbd]

Additionally, third-party keyboards make the input box completely hidden. The chat seems to treat third-party keyboards as having no height.

> [image: third-party]

iOS 9.2.1 / Mobile Safari

<sub>There is no problem in old (stable) design but it doesn't fix the input box to bottom!</sub>

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Shog9 I'm using Mobile Safari.

Comment: This problem also seems to exist with alternative keyboards. Swift Keyboard, for example, does this. @Shog9

Comment: Perhaps this is a problem with those keyboards, though.

Comment: I would strongly recommend blaming Safari...

Comment: @Shog9 Are you suggesting that I try an alternative browser?

Comment: Does Apple allow those now? If so, then yes.

Comment: @Shog9 Chrome for iOS will not scroll the screen up at first, but it will manually, or as soon as you start typing. That's good enough for me. I didn't know there was Chrome for iOS.

Comment: @fredsbend Chrome for smartphones is an app, just like any other app. No reason for Apple to ban/block it.

Comment: @Sha well, they didn't allow it for some time and I think I remember Chrome for iOS is actually the Safari render engine in a Google skin.